# ie6 fix requires background. need a workaround

Tags: css, background, internet-explorer-6

Trying to implement this gallery on my website.

http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/

It is noted in the css file that the next and previous buttons won't show up in IE6 unless a nonexistent background image is applied to `.ad-gallery .ad-image-wrapper .ad-prev, .ad-gallery .ad-image-wrapper .ad-next`. The code they used is invalid, but it works. I have also tried using a color instead and it does work, but not what I wanted.

I don't want to point to a nonexistent image file or a blank.gif if possible. Does anyone know what causes this problem in IE6 and if there is a pure css workaround? `zoom: 1` does not work in this case.

Comment: IE6.... what is IE6? ;) use the background.

Comment: just trying to make the website work across as many browsers as possible. im not the type that would put a banner across the top of my site telling people to "upgrade" or which browser/resolution to use..

Comment: 3,72% (and falling) of worldwide users still use IE6. http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201006-201106

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume your IE6 requirement is referring to the following snippet from the [jQuery AD Gallery](http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/) plugin's stylesheet, [jquery.ad-gallery.css](http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/jquery.ad-gallery.css):

```
.ad-gallery .ad-image-wrapper .ad-prev, .ad-gallery .ad-image-wrapper .ad-next {
      /* Or else IE will hide it */
      background: url(non-existing.jpg)\9;
    }
```

The `\9` at the end of the background shorthand rule is actually a **CSS Hack targeting IE6, IE7 and IE8** — not just IE6.

> *Note: Paul Irish wrote a [Comprehensive List
>   of Browser-Specific CSS Hacks](http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/) back
>   in 2009 which highlighted this
>   attribute parsing bug in IE/Win:*
>
> ```
> /* IE6, IE7, IE8 */
> #diecinueve { color: blue\9; }
> ```

If you don't want to use a 1 pixel transparent `spacer.gif` or *non-existent file* for IE (which would throw a 404 error), just modify the CSS to re-use one of the existing images in the gallery but specify the background-position's X and Y property to be off the screen:

```
.ad-gallery .ad-image-wrapper .ad-prev, .ad-gallery .ad-image-wrapper .ad-next {
    /* Or else IE will hide it */
    background: url(ad_next.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px\9;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

This creative work-a-round will allow IE 6-8 to display the previous and next links, but won't actually show the specified background image file, since the X and Y values position the background completely off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Don't support Internet Explorer 6. It's over 10 years old. Recommend your users upgrade Internet Explorer or switch to a different browser. Problem solved!